# What is the name of this indoor plant/tree with big dark green leaves?

Tags: identification, trees, houseplants, indoors

Can anyone tell me the name of this indoor plant/tree?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's [Ficus benjamina](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ficus_benjamina) and it looks like its suffered a bit of drought or sunburn judging by the yellow patches.